# SharePoint Audit logs

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-usage

I don't think this is a possibility, but i am going to ask it anyway.

I am looking for a way to see usage data, from multiple years back. 
For example, i want to see the amount of Sites created or used in 2018 compared to 2019.

Is there anyway of getting this data?
i checked;
- O365 compliance and security center audit log
- SharePoint admin center
- Site activity (site specific)
- O365 usage reports

They all go either one month or a max of 180 days back, which is not enough for me.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

That data is not preserved, though the Site creation timestamp is. Under the SharePoint admin center at https://tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement there is a creation date for each site.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Imade an export of this, to get the dates, so at least i got some insight!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge that is not possible to track usage data for many years ago. Even for audit log with E5 license, Audit records for Azure Active Directory, Exchange, and SharePoint activity are retained for one year.

Comment: okay, so if we'd want to accomplish this, i'd have to find a way to create automatic exports in the future, every so many months, and put them together manually.